# jquery - click on parent makes action, but on children not

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this element in html

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="showed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe magnam, ea est quo voluptate a necessitatibus facere explicabo. Doloribus odio, atque voluptatibus. Libero est, eius totam incidunt eaque debitis reprehenderit.</p>
    <a href="#" class="nope">AA</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hided">Im hided</div>
</div>
```

Im hiding div with class hided with css

```
.item {
  border:  2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hided {
  display: none;
}
```

And with jQuery I'm allowing swtiching displaying .hidded div.

```
$(".item").on("click", function(){
  $(this).find(".hided").toggle();
});
```

What I don't know is how to avoid toggling if user clicks on link element (that with .nope class).

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is not the `.nope` element.

```js
$(".item").on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(':not(.nope)'))
  // or if (!$(e.target).hasClass('nope'))
    $(this).find(".hided").toggle();
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hided {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="showed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe magnam, ea est quo voluptate a necessitatibus facere explicabo. Doloribus odio, atque voluptatibus. Libero est, eius totam incidunt eaque debitis reprehenderit.</p>
    <a href="#" class="nope">AA</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hided">Im hided</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, `e.target` is you current clicked element `hasClass` will change that `nope` class is exists on that element.

```js
$(".item").on("click", function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('nope'))
  {
    $(this).find(".hided").toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  border:  2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hided {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="showed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe magnam, ea est quo voluptate a necessitatibus facere explicabo. Doloribus odio, atque voluptatibus. Libero est, eius totam incidunt eaque debitis reprehenderit.</p>
    <a href="#" class="nope">AA</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hided">Im hided</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```